# Why am I getting a 505 when connecting to GitHub?

Tags: github, heroku, integration

I've been getting an "Internal Server Error" message when trying to authorize GitHub on Heroku. How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku and Github : Items could not be retrieved, Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892543/heroku-and-github-items-could-not-be-retrieved-internal-server-error)

Answer (score 0):

Github auth tokens were recently comprised of Heroku. As a procation, they made it so no new auth tokens would be issued. We do not know when they will start issuing them again. You can view this in more detail on their [support page](https://help.heroku.com/).