# Heroku cannot connect to Github

Tags: github, heroku, deployment, oauth, repository

A week ago everything it was normal with my app deployment on Heroku using my Github repository.

Now, HerokuApp doesn't have access to my github and everytime i try to connect it shows me this error:

"Couldn't connect to GitHub
Error: remote was closed, authorization was denied, or an authentication message otherwise not received before the window closed."

[Couldn't connect to GitHub Error: remote was closed, authorization was denied, or an authentication message otherwise not received before the window closed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTatU.png)

Does anybody know what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep.  This is a known issue happening at Heroku.

Check this other answer:  [Heroku Account not connecting to Github [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892543/heroku-and-github-items-could-not-be-retrieved-internal-server-error)