# Reconnect Heroku Pipeline gives "internal server error"

Tags: github, heroku

I recently changed my github name to not be my actual name, but now I am getting an error after reauthorizing heroku access to my github account.  It looks like it is successful, but a red message shows up on the pipeline console which states:

*Item could not be retrieved:
Internal Server Error*

Any ideas how to fix this?  I tried opening a ticket because I think heroku's backend is at fault, but I am on a free account, so no tickets allowed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This has nothing to do with renaming your account. It is an ongoing issue related to Heroku's GitHub integration, which is currently disabled. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Another person already reported, but I missed it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71905270/14749871

Comment: Yes, that's the question I linked as a duplicate.