# Heroku Internal Error when trying to re-authorize GitHub

Tags: github, heroku

When I am trying to authorize Heroku to use GitHub I am receiving an Internal Server Error. What is it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71892543/3001761.

Comment: Please remember to search before asking new questions. See [ask].