# Why doesn't my heroku app update from CLI or Git?

Tags: git, github, heroku, heroku-cli

I have a running heroku app but every time i try to push what I added to the project to heroku the app still works and in the dashboard there's written "Deployed" but when i try it is still in the older version.
I tried to follow some guides but they didn't work for me (for example the answer from here: [Heroku and Github : Items could not be retrieved, Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892543/heroku-and-github-items-could-not-be-retrieved-internal-server-error)) 
I used to do automatic deploys using github but since that doesn't work anymore i'm using git to push to the repo and to heroku manually

P.S
My app runs on java

Answer (score 0):

run `heroku ps` to check what runs on the server maybe a previous process didn't went down

Comment: i ran the command but it doesn't seem that there is something wrong, it just says that i have an app running with free dynos

Comment: you can run heroku run bash and when inside your dyno you can check the file system to examin what exactly what was deployed and what happend wrong