# Heroku Pipeline with Github

Tags: github, heroku, heroku-ci

Since the link between Github and Heroku is [currently broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892543/heroku-and-github-items-could-not-be-retrieved-internal-server-error) is it possible to manually add `Review Apps` to my [pipeline](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines) using Heroku CLI?