# Change github repo for deployed heroku project

Tags: reactjs, github, heroku, deployment, mern

I am looking to create a new portfolio. The current one is just using nodejs / express and the basics. It is already deployed on heroku. I would like to maintain / keep the same portfolio project link.

Where I have a question:...
I either want to add react to existing portfolio and refactor/enhance or create a new react app and deploy to heroku with the same project name / deployment. My research says I can't fully add react to existing project. (Please correct me if i am wrong). Am I wrong? If i am right.. I would create a new react app / portfolio and then want to change the github repo associated with the heroku project? Can I do this? I could not find the info in their docs. THANK YOU!!

Comment: "My research says I can't fully add react to existing project"—what do you mean by this? "If i am right.. I would create a new react app / portfolio and then want to change the github repo associated with the heroku project? Can I do this?"—sure, what's stopping you? Just deploy the new project to the existing app. (Note that [GitHub integration is currently disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71892543/354577), so you'll have to use an alternate method like direct `git push`ing.)

Comment: Just newer to this world and wasn't sure if I could just push it to the same heroku and write over the previous one... I knew I could create everything else new... I was curious about adding react to an existing express generated app/portfolio.. normally I would start with "create react app" if i wanted to use react.. in this case I dont think you can add react to the express generated app I already made.. im not seeing commands/process for it.. unless I add in scripts.. just going to create a new portfolio!..Thanks!