# `Connect to Github` deployment method is failing

Tags: heroku

When I click the deployment method option `Connect to Github` it asks for integration in github with after allowing replies back with `Internal Server Error` when initializing the deployment method.

How can i get it working?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. I found this, hope it can help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892543/heroku-and-github-items-could-not-be-retrieved-internal-server-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892543/heroku-and-github-items-could-not-be-retrieved-internal-server-error)

Comment: Please remember to search for existing questions before asking a new one, as described in [ask]. This issue has been ongoing for a month.