# Cannot deploy app via Github or Heroku Git

Tags: git, github, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app on Heroku, but the github (connect to github), in the Deploy tab, gives internal server error so i tried with heroku Cli.

I've downloaded my repo, i've cloned the repo form git hub with

```
$ heroku git:clone -a myapp
$ cd myapp
```

Then i've put all my files that folder and did the classic commit push for git:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "text"
$ git push heroku master
```

Then i tried also to switch to main branch with these commands: https://help.heroku.com/O0EXQZTA/how-do-i-switch-branches-from-master-to-main, but nothing, in the  App Deploy nothing appears, still the "tutorial" on how to deploy the app.

Advice on how to deploy apps now, that github is stopped?

Thank you

Comment: "but the github (connect to github), in the Deploy tab, gives internal server error"—yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71892543/354577

Comment: Why did you clone from Heroku? Don't you already have a local copy?

Comment: FYI, [GitHub integration has been re-enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71895325/354577).